# CSS not loading using Node.js and express.static

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I'm currently working on a web project using Node.js and Express, and I'm facing an issue with my CSS not loading properly when serving the static files. I've tried using express.static, but it doesn't seem to work as expected. Here's a brief overview of my folder structure and code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'Public')));

app.post('/subscribe', (req, res) => {
  const email = req.body.email;
  
  fs.appendFile('subscribers.txt', email + '\n', (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
  });

  res.send('Thank you for subscribing!');
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'Public', 'Home', 'Home.html'));
});


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Home.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3720a64a77.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
```

```json
{
  "name": "email-subscription",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  }
}
```

[image: File Directory]

I am new to coding, and so deeply appreciate any help/advice!

Comment: Could be the CSS path: app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'Public'))); The '..' and the filename too href="Home.css"> Sometimes the caps cause problems Home.css. Try home.css for the path and filename

Comment: Inside your browser URL  type: domain name.com/path to home.css. To check the error in the console panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Express server is serving the whole `Public` directory, but the CSS file `Home.css` is in `Public/Home/Home.css`, so you need to use the path `Home/Home.css` (relative to the directory being served, not to the HTML file) to get your CSS file

Just change this line in your HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Home.css">
```

to this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Home/Home.css">
```

Comment: If this answer solved your issue,  then you can mark it as correct to indicate that it worked for you and to guide others with the same issue in the future.

Comment: Actually, the CSS link should probably be `/Home/Home.css` so it will work in any page, even a page that isn't top level path (absolute path URL instead of relative path URL).